# Python: downsample a population using frequency data

Tags: python, random, sampling, downsampling

Given a data series representing frequencies of elements in a population, what would be the easiest way to downsample it ?

The following population: `pop = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']`

Can be summeriezed as: `freq = {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}`

Using the simple: `from collections import Counter; Counter(pop)`

To randomly downsample that population to 5 individuals I can do:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pop = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
>>> smaller_pop = sample(pop, 5)
>>> smaller_freq = Counter(smaller_pop)
>>> print smaller_freq
Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 1, 'b': 1})
```

But I'm searching for a way to do this directly from the `freq` information without having to build the `pop` list. You will agree that proceeding like this should not be necessary:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> flatten = lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist]
>>> freq = {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
>>> pop = flatten([[k]*v for k,v in freq.items()])
>>> smaller_pop = sample(pop, 5)
>>> smaller_freq = Counter(smaller_pop)
>>> print smaller_freq
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

For memory considerations and speed requirements, I would like to avoid placing in memory the `pop` list. This can surely be done using some type of weighted random generator.

Comment: Would you be interested in an approximate solution? Since you are interested in downsampling, presumably the values in `freq` are very large. If so, you could floordiv (`//`) them all by some factor, then enumerate the smaller `freq` dict, and take a sample of that.

Comment: An exact algorithm is more what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic algorithm that downsamples frequencies:

```
import random
import bisect
import collections

def downsample(freq, n):
    cumsums = []
    total = 0
    choices, weights = zip(*freq.items())
    for weight in weights:
        total += weight
        cumsums.append(total)
    assert 0 <= n <= total
    result = collections.Counter()
    for _ in range(n):
        rnd = random.uniform(0, total)
        i = bisect.bisect(cumsums, rnd)
        result[choices[i]] += 1
        cumsums = [c if idx<i else c-1 for idx, c in enumerate(cumsums)]
        total -= 1
    return result

freq = {'a': 5, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1}
print(downsample(freq, 5))
```

which prints results like

```
Counter({'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: That's it, using the bisect. That seems logical now that I see it. Thanks.